# Descargar PDF function.php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el function.php de wordpres

```
<a class="btn-pdf" href="'.$tipo_catalogo["pdf"]["url"].'">PDF</a>
```

Pero me abre una pestaña, ya que es es un link. Como hago para que en vez de abrirlo lo descargue?

(el pdf lo coge de un campo de custom fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añadir donwload a la etiqueta a. La respondo por si alguien tiene la duda.

```
<a class="btn-pdf" href="'.$tipo_catalogo["pdf"]["url"].'" donwload >PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

añade esto a tu .htaccess

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Comment: lo añado tal cual a la ultima linea?

Comment: Si, preferiblemente al principio del .htaccess y ya nos dices si funcionó.